# Email Logs - Viewing the Content of the email sent from salesforce

Tags: apex, email

Using email log I was able to obtain the emails sent from Salesforce.com

But from the email logs I am not able to read the actual content.

Also checked in the documentation ..they have not said that the log will store the actual content itself.

Is there any way for me to get this info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email log is a CSV file that stores the following information about emails sent over the past 30 days:

- The email address of each email sender and recipient
- The date and time each email was sent
- The delivery status of each email
- Any error code associated with each email

These logs are intended primarily for troubleshooting purposes, not as a record or back-up of what emails were sent from the org. For more on this, see [What Are Email Logs?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_logs.htm&language=en_US)

When using the `sendEmail()` method, if the optional `saveAsActivity` field is set to `True`, an email is saved as an `Activity`. However, this only applies if the recipient list is based on a `targetObjectId` or `targetObjectIds`.

You may also want to read this Success Community Answer [Log an activity when firing a workflow email alert](https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&id=90630000000h2LbAAI) regarding how to work around the problem of workflow emails to customers not being logged as activities.